# ReactJS Warning: TextField is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting this error below.

> Warning: TextField is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

I am using material-ui.

Here is my code:

```
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { errorText: '', value:this.props }
  }

  phone(event) {
    var strRegExpMobile=/^\d{10}$/;
    if (event.target.value.match(strRegExpMobile)) {
      this.setState({ errorText: '',
                        phone:event.target.value
                     })
    } else {
      this.setState({ errorText: 'Invalid format' })
    }
  }
  handleSubmit(event){
    alert("submit");
    var data={
        phone:this.state.phone
    }
    console.log(data)
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <TextField hintText="Phone"
           floatingLabelText="Phone"
           name="phone"
           value={this.state.phone}
           errorText= {this.state.errorText}
           onChange={this.phone.bind(this)}/>

          <RaisedButton label="Submit" 
           primary={true} 
           onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Can any one tell where I am wrong?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Reason is, you didn't define the `phone` in `state` variable so on initial rendering TextField will be treated as **uncontrolled component** because value property will have `undefined` value.

In this line

`value = {this.state.phone}`  => **this.state.phone is undefined initially**

To fix this define phone in state variable, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
        errorText: '', 
        value:this.props, 
        phone: '' 
    }
}
```

Or define the value property by using [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) like this:

```
value = {this.state.phone || ''}      //(undefined || '') = ''
```

Comment: it will accept the value, once you do setState in onChange function that value will get populated in TextField.

Comment: @Sweety If you are not able to change text then see if you are entering a valid text format as mentioned in your phone function by the regex, or see if you get any error in console. Otherwise this answer must be sufficient

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438045/react-pass-parent-value-to-child-input-value
Another solution is to use defaultValue attribute, instead of value attribute.
Root cause is beautifuly explained in this link -
https://github.com/twisty/formsy-react-components/issues/66 

Quoting Twisty's comment - 
`if you initially pass undefined or null as the value prop, the component starts life as an "uncontrolled" component. Once you interact with the component, we set a value and react changes it to a "controlled" component, and issues the warning.`

Answer (score 14):

Because your value is undefined that's why you are getting this error

Try this

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <TextField hintText="Phone"
           floatingLabelText="Phone"
           name="phone"
           value={this.state.phone || ''}
           errorText= {this.state.errorText}
           onChange={this.phone.bind(this)}/>

          <RaisedButton label="Submit" 
           primary={true} 
           onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
```