# react - pass parent value to child input value

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs. 
What is the proper way to pass the parent value to child `setState`, I am having error says below, and I am unable to change input value, the value looks correct but unable to be changed.

> "is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled.
>   Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or
>   vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input
>   element for the lifetime of the component"

```
export default class parent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: ''
        }
    }

    updateFun(){
        this.setState({title: 'Parents title'});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.updateFun()}> Update </button>
            <Child title = {this.state.title}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: ''
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <input 
                id="title" 
                type="text"
                value={this.props.title}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: i think error is not in this part, this code looks proper, check working [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/e1tj6x2b/) there is one issue only, name of the parent component, it should be Parent check this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/html-is-not-rendering-in-the-browser-react-js/42110172#42110172) for reason.

Comment: I agree with @MayankShukla. The code works fine as you posted it. It is, however, a bit unclear exactly what you want to do. Do you want the child to have its own state or should the Parent control all states? You have a title state in your Child that you never use. It's also unclear why you have a button that updates the input value with a static text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `defaultValue` instead of `value`. Also you must add `onChange` handler to your input. To handle input changes.

Child example

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: props.title
    }

    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
}

handler(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);

    this.setState({title: event.target.value});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <input 
            id="title" 
            type="text"
            defaultValue={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.handler}
            />
        </div>
    )
}}
```

Comment: Worked nicely for me. Also noticed that the constructor block could be avoided. Thanks.